# I am developer and started managing team. I want to learn how to create wireframe. Can anyone advice?

Tags: website-design, mobile, wireframing

Basically I want to understand how everything works in respective of designers when it comes to mobile or web Development.

I do not want to be designer I want to how things work so that I can work better with them

Comment: Hi Iva. People write hundred-pages books on that, what exactly do you expect as an answer? (I think currently the answer is 42) You'll probably want to ask a less broad question.

Comment: Sounds like a 4-year college course would be a good start.

Comment: Hire a UI designer that gives your team the experience you need.

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE! Your edit clarifies the question, but I'm afraid it's still a bad fit for the site. It's still way too broad. You ask us to explain a whole field of work. I can't imagine how to boil it down to a relatively short answer.

Comment: You kind of *have* to be in the industry to "know how things work". I can hire an electrician.. but knowing how to rewire a house is well outside the scope of knowledge I should need. I can see my doctor, but knowing how all aspects of the body medically function is again outside the scope of knowledge I should need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either become a designer or *learn to think* like a designer (long-term process) or just add a designer to your team (tomorrow) and let the designer do his part.